# VSCode Intellisense Suddenly Stopped Working For All Workspaces

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense, emmet

Seemingly around the time I updated Visual Studio (not Vscode) and installed some other packages, my VSCode autocomplete / intellisense stopped working for what appears to be every language except HTML, in every project. It could be unrelated to my updating but I find it strange it seems to have been since then.

I can no longer type 'classN' in React JavaScript / JSX to get autocomplete selections 'className', for example. This is likewise for every language except for HTML which I get autocomplete suggestions for elements.

The only thing that populates every single time for everything else is this:

[image]

Nothing I've researched, from 'restarting vscode' to 'downgrading C# language extension', has worked. I'm also quite confused by all these configurations and emmet vs intellisense vs snippets, then people start talking about language packs and suddenly it's a package.json config, so I'm very confused in general.

Thank you, in advance, for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out:

In VSCode, navigate to '*Extensions*' in the navbar > search '**@builtin TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features**' and make sure this is **Enabled**